# IE 10 lack of search preferences

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-developer-tools

In my project, I am using IE10 to fix some bugs. The project has many files with same name main.js in different folders. Something like below:

```
JS (folder)
  --> folderOne
      -- main.js
  --> folderTwo
      -- main.js
  --> folderThree
      -- main.js
```

Now when I am in need of select a file which is in folder `folderThree`, I am clicking on [`file chooser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is showing all the js files with names `main.js`. Now to get my needed file, I need to hover over all the files one by one to check the directory from which the file has been originated. This process is really annoying. I think there must be some other alternative or may be it has been ignored by IE developers. Anyway to resolve this?

In Mozilla firebug, a user can search for a filename based on the folder name which is really user friendly(IMHO).

PS: The above scenario is just example. Actually, in my project I have many folders with same file name.

Comment: Question: you are having same file in all folders or its different files, with same name!!?... I am asking this to have work around, as IE was never perfect, and I think they are not planning to become one either..

Comment: @MarmiK I have different files with same name in different folders.

Comment: Oh ok... in that case we can use only console methods.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj819729(v=vs.85).aspx >> command>> dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old post states FireBug Lite works with IE,

[`Old Post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508449/alternatives-to-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-10-metro)

I think that will solve the problem easily, as IE. [`Console methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may work or not, but [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) will do for sure.. :)

Its also having js version that you can incluse in the `<head>` of html file..

there is one trick to this refer this [`video`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLJ2RaNZ22E), that adds code to shortcut in IE 10 and firebug works

I hope this will do,